Any additional advantage to keeping mosfets cool?
I know there is nothing to worry about if the operating temperature of a mosfet is under 100 degree C and manufacturers usually don't bother to install a heatsink if the mosfet is operating under this temperature. But from the mosfet efficiency standpoint or for the sake of current and signal stability, is there any additional advantage to keeping a mosfet cool? I ask this question, because I have bunch of small heatsinks lying around. I tried to give them a second life before deciding to throw them away.

Great question, upvoted! This comment is not really relevant but I hope is helpful. In someone else's words "English is extremely stingy with commas". Meaning you don't put one before 'because'. Unlike in my language and probably most others.

Reliability generally improves the cooler the part is. 100°C with normal room ambient temperature is actually very hot for an application that should last a long time, and particularly if the environment can get very hot.
As well, the Rds(on) of a MOSFET increases with temperature so the conduction losses get worse as the temperature increases. Here, from the datasheet, is the typical Rds(on) vs. temperature behavior of the popular IRLZ44 MOSFET:

As you can see, at 100°C it's already 50% worse than at room temperature, and gets up to about double at Tj(max). Conduction losses in watts are proportional to resistance.
The threshold voltage also shifts with temperature, and the leakage typically doubles every 10°C but those may not be too important for MOSFETs.
Schottky diodes can have dramatically high leakage at Tj(max), hundreds of mA. Analog circuitry can be affected, of course. Reducing the temperature at 'hot spots' in the device can improve overall performance if it's an analog device and can improve overall life- the MOSFETs are not only heating themselves but also perhaps nearby electrolytic capacitors, which have limited life that is highly temperature-dependent.

As well as losses (i.e. inefficiency) going up with temperature, you'd (@ST2008) need to consider the possibility of thermal runaway - it gets hotter, so RDS_on goes up, so self heating goes up, so it gets hotter, and so on until something breaks

Rough rule of thumb is semiconductor lifetime is halved for every 10C increase in junction temperature. Adding even a small heatsink to a TO-220 could easily drop it by 50-60C.

This. I also use this rule of thumb, and I am pretty sure its origin was in the reliability calculations in the MIL-HDBK standard that has a temperature factor (all of those obtained through statistics).

Yes, RDson can increase with temperature. Keeping the temperature low can help decrease the power dissipated in the device.

Switching energy increases with temperature as well, though I believe it's typically a smaller proportion than Rdson.
